# How to find all pairs in an array such that the sum of the pair equals the product of the pair efficiently?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I know the brute-force approach. Is there a way to do it in less than O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity?

Comment: Ignore the array for now; can you think of any numbers where `a+b == a*b`? What do they have to be?

Comment: fyi, this is an active CodeChef challenge: https://www.codechef.com/DEC19B/problems/PLMU

Answer (score 2):

Look at the problem mathematically:

```
a * b = a + b

b(a - 1) = a    [Subtract b]

b = a / (a - 1) [where a =/= 1]
```

That will let you precalculate pairs [a, b] like [0, 0], [1.5, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1.5], ...

Sorting the array will make searching for known pairs faster.  Note also that if [x, y] meets the criterion then [y, x] also meets it.  That will roughly halve your search time.